# Group SQL results together?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query on my website which brings back contents of a column cell when another cell is equal to a certain number.

However my PHP code only pick ups the content in the first row it comes to. Is there a way I can group/combine the other row results?

```
function bookmarkTags($siteID) {

    $id = $siteID;

    $db = new DB();
    $db->connect();

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM share WHERE site_id = $id");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $delimiter = " ";
    $tags = explode($delimiter, $result['tags']);

    return $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a while loop, the following code is untested.

```
$delimiter = " ";
$tags = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM share WHERE site_id = $id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $tags_new = explode($delimiter, $row['tags']);
    $tags = array_merge($tags , $tags_new);
}
```

Note:

Also look into mysqli and PDO, mysql_* functions are history.